# Using file_get_contents with Gravity Forms uploads folder to create images in the media library returning false

Tags: php, functions, uploads, plugin-gravity-forms

I am using Gravity forms which is uploading media and recreating the image into the relevant media folder over https.

However, on my server, this doesn't appear to be reading the Gravity File folder, or the contents of the image correctly. The files are being created however with no data from the image. (I have included my full upload code below. I found an article that "file_get_contents" had issues in regards to SSLs locally, and this appears to be working locally as intended.

Thoughts / guidance appreciated

(Note, Prefix is just an additional parameter, and obviously $imgArr is an array of image URLs that i am passing from the Gravity Form by form of

`json_encode($entity[x])`

name is from another variable from the Gravity form as an entity also.

Thankyou in advance.

```
function createImage($prefix, $imgArr, $name){

    $i = 1;
    //Sorting out the URLs prior to creation
    foreach($imgArr as $url) {

            $finalUrl = str_replace('""', '',$url);
            $newName = $name . $prefix . '-'. $i;
            $i++;


            $arrContextOptions=array(
                "ssl"=>array(
                "verify_peer"=>false,
                "verify_peer_name"=>false,
                ),
            );

            $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
            $image_data = file_get_contents($finalUrl, false, stream_context_create($arrContextOptions));

            //Strip out the old filename and replace with the befores name
            $slash = strrpos($finalUrl, '/', 0);
            $slash++;
            $fileName = array_pop(str_split($finalUrl, $slash));
            $fileExt =  array_pop(explode('.', $fileName));
            $newFileName = $newName . '.' . $fileExt;

            if(wp_mkdir_p($upload_dir['path']))
                $file = $upload_dir['path'] . '/' . $newFileName;
            else
                $file = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/' . $newFileName;
            file_put_contents($file, $image_data);

            $wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype($newFileName, null);
                $upload_id = array(
                    'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
                    'post_title'=> sanitize_file_name($newFileName),
                    'post_content'   => '',
                    'post_status'    => 'inherit'
            );

            $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $upload_id, $file, $post_ID);

            if (!is_wp_error($attach_id)) {
                require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );
                $attachment_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id,  $file );
                wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id,  $attachment_data );
                set_post_thumbnail( $post_ID, $attachment_data );
            }

            //Return the uploaded image ID, so to use to update the ACF field

    }
}
```

Comment: On gfrom submission, what are you trying to do with the submitted images? Are you trying to basically add the submitted uploads to an acf img/file or gallery field as a true post related media item(s)? If so can you expand your question to see the gfrom filter post creation containing the `createImage()` function?

Answer (score 1):

I noticed in your comment...

> Return the uploaded image ID, so to use to update the ACF field

Here is two functions which may help you out...

- `gf_handle_attachments()` to handle converting gform submission image file into wordpress media attachment. Returning media (attachment) id.
- `gf_upload_to_media_acf()` to handle gform submitted image or multiple images and update defined acf (image, file or gallery) field with media attachment(s).

> File types `jpeg`, `jpg`, `png`, and `gif` will only work with this as
> far as i've tested. File type `pdf` does not like being added to acf
> `image` and `gallery` fields. The `pdf` gets added still but wordpress
> does **not** create any previews.

`$filename` parameter is not just the filename, it is the full file url via `https` or `http`. Basically which ever protocol the gform submits over.

Here is the `gf_handle_attachments()` function which handles converting a single `$filename` into a wordpress media attachment. Returning the attachment id.

```
// save image to media library and then save the image to acf field
function gf_handle_attachments($filename, $parent_post_id) {

    // check the type of file
    // we'll use this as the 'post_mime_type'
    $file_type = wp_check_filetype( basename( $filename ), null );

    // get the path to the upload directory
    $wp_upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();

    // prepare an array of attachment post data
    $attachment = [
        'guid'           => $wp_upload_dir['url'] . '/' . basename( $filename ),
        'post_mime_type' => $file_type['type'],
        'post_title'     => preg_replace( '/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename( $filename ) ),
        'post_content'   => '',
        'post_status'    => 'inherit'
    ];

    // insert the attachment
    $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment($attachment, $filename, $parent_post_id);

    // make sure that this file is included, as wp_generate_attachment_metadata() depends on it
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );

    // generate the metadata for the attachment, and update the database record
    $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata($attach_id,$filename);
    wp_update_attachment_metadata($attach_id, $attach_data);

    // delete file from gf uploads
    //unlink($filename);

    // return attachment id
    return $attach_id;

}
```

This is the `gf_upload_to_media_acf()` function which takes the submitted gfrom file upload or gfrom multi-file uploads entry `$value` and adds them to the defined acf (image, file or gallery) `$field` into defined `$post_id`.

```
// upload gf uploads media to post acf field
function gf_upload_to_media_acf($value, $post_id, $field) {

    // if entry value begins with json brackets (gfrom multi-file upload entry)
    if(substr($value,0,2) === '["') {

        // decode gfrom entry value into array
        $filenames = json_decode(stripslashes($value));

        // lets begin multiple attachment array
        $attach_ids = [];

        // for each filenames as filename
        foreach ($filenames as $filename) {

            // handle each filename to wordpress media attachment linked to post
            $attach_ids[] = gf_handle_attachments($filename, $post_id);

        }

        // update acf (gallery) field with the attachment ids
        update_field($field, $attach_ids, $post_id);

    // else if single gform image upload entry
    } else {

        // handle single media attachment and return attachment id
        $attach_id = gf_handle_attachments($value, $post_id);

        // update acf (image, file or gallery) field for post with the attachment id
        update_field($field, $attach_id, $post_id);

    }

}
```

---

Here is example usage using `gform_confirmation` filter which creates a new post and then uses `update_entry_data_fields()` function passing entry data which then handles specified entry fields (file uploads)...

```
// filter to fire when gfrom id 1 hits confirmation
add_filter('gform_confirmation_1', 'form_confirmation', 10, 4 );

// form confirmation function for above gform filter
function form_confirmation($confirmation, $form, $entry, $ajax) {

    // new post settings array
    $post = [
        'post_type'     => 'post',
        'post_status'   => 'pending'
    ];

    // create new post for our submission using post array settings and return the newly created post id to result variable
    $result = wp_insert_post($post);

    // if result post id and is not a wp_error then...
    if($result && !is_wp_error($result)) {

        // get the created result post id
        $post_id = $result;

        // create our post title
        $title = 'Post #' . $post_id;

        // new submission array to use to update the created post
        $submission = [
            'ID'            => $post_id,
            'post_title'    => $title,
            'post_name'     => sanitize_title($title)
        ];

        // update the created submission post with new submission array data
        wp_update_post($submission);

        // update this post acf fields with entry data
        update_entry_data_fields($post_id, $entry);

        // return submission post id if you wana 
        return $post_id;

    }

    // return false
    return false;

}
```

This `update_entry_data_fields()` function is where we use `gf_upload_to_media_acf()` function for gform submission file upload(s) entry data...

```
// update acf fields or anything else for defined post id using gform submission entry array data
function update_entry_data_fields($post_id, $entry) {

    // if form submission entry is array
    if(is_array($entry)) {

        // for each entry item
        foreach ($entry as $key => $value) {

            // if entry key is our gform file upload or multi-file upload entry field
            if($key === '1.8') {

                // if we have a entry value
                if($value) {

                    // image, file or gallery acf field name
                    $acf_field = 'acf_field_name';

                    // handle the media attachment(s) creation and add attachment(s) to acf (image, file, or gallery) field via acf_field_name
                    gf_upload_to_media_acf($value, $post_id, $acf_field);

                }

            }

        }

    }

}
```